# Printing output from a basic C script

Tags: c

**It appears that the issue is a result of Powershell but do correct me if I am wrong. Standard CMD produces the exe file.**

I am new to C - moving from MATLAB and Python - and am struggling with compiling the code in windows powershell.

I have written a basic code, based on an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

When i run this in windows powershell using

```
'gcc .\helloworld.c -o .\helloworld'
```

but this prints nothing and I am unsure why. I have also tried the IDEs like codelite and VisualStudio with no success.

**Update**

**Based on the comments I have no executable file produced which appears to be the problem.**

If anyone can help me that would be great!

Comment: "this prints nothing" What did you expect it to print? I'd expect an output file being generated and the compiler being like "Yeth, marthter."

Comment: Or "mithreth" of course.... or "your magnifithenthe"....

Comment: It prints nothing because `gcc` prints nothing is nothing bad happened

Comment: Ok, I assumed that it would print the statement in the compiler? 

It also doesn't produce an output file in the file source location.

Comment: There are two steps:  (1) compile and link your program (2) Run your program.  You only did step 1.  This should have produced an executable named `helloworld`, which you now need to run.  Windows may have some requirement that it end in `.exe` (not sure about that).

Comment: Perhaps grab a good C book or tutorial? Programming by guessing is not usually very productive.

Comment: @TomKarzes So i should have a file to run but this is not in my system after i run the above suggested code.

Comment: @kaylum I would take recommendations

Comment: Your comment contains the information that no file whatsoever is generated. That is an important info, please [edit] it into the question itself.

Comment: @TomKarzes this didn't succeed either...

Comment: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @4386427 by simpliy using 'ls' in the command line

Or I can visually check in the file browser but neither have it

Comment: hmmm. Is `ls` a powershell command... anyway - have you tried a "normal" cmd window?

Comment: @4386427 yes, powershell uses linux based commands (something I am more familiar with) - hence why I hadn't used the normal CMD mode. 

It appears that Powershell doesn't like running C for producing the exe file but cmd does! Thank you all for your help, hopefully there are no more issues on this

Comment: @TomKarzes the extension is added by the compiler, no need to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gcc is a compiler which makes an output file.
You are used to python and Matlab. Python is an interpreted language so you can get outputs without making an executable file.

For C you make an output file which is an executable which you run to get the desired results. Assuming your file name is `helloworld.c` Run the following :

```
gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

This will create a file by name of `helloworld` in that directory.
To execute the file you need to do `./<output_filename>` which in your case would be `./helloworld` and then you should get your output/printing

Comment: I think your answer overlapped with OP clarifying that no file is generated.... Please double check, I currently get the impression that this is not a solution to the described problem (if comments are included).

Comment: Exactly, I didn't initially realise I would get an executible file to run but now it appears that is the issue.

Comment: @Yunnosch I didn't realise no output file is being generated, I will modify the answer accordingly...

Comment: That is why I mentioned "overlap". You cannot really be blamed. If you however update your answer you will be safe from misunderstandings....

Comment: @Yunnosch Can you please be kind enough to edit the answer, I can't figure out a way to write that and mention the 'overlap' in words.

Comment: No I can't, not knowing the solution either. More debugging info is needed, but hard to tell which.... If you cannot answer the question as asked now, I recommend to delete the answer. (I cannot blame OP for a moving target question either....)